# progress bar update in android

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I'm developing an android application. Working on vertical progress bar.
 When I add new item, the item is associated with some percentage value say 30%.
 The progress bar need to update from 0% to 30%. And if I add another item with percentage value say 40%, the progress bar need to `update from 30% to 70%(30+40)`.
 How can I do this. Sample code would be helpful. I have posted my code here.

```
public class VerticalProgressBar extends Activity {

Button buttonStart;
ProgressBar vProgressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verticalprogressbar);
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    vProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.vprogressbar);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonStart.setClickable(false);
            new asyncTaskUpdateProgress().execute();
        }
    });

}

public class asyncTaskUpdateProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    int progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        buttonStart.setClickable(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progress = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vProgressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (progress < 100) {

            progress++;
            publishProgress(progress);
            SystemClock.sleep(100);

        }
        return null;

      }

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onProgressUpdate`, use this to add the value to the current progress:

```
vProgressBar.setProgress(vProgressBar.getProgress() + values[0]);
```

And in `doInBackground` where you presumably have your "item", something like:

```
publishProgress(item.getPercentageValue());
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I got about the first line of your code. But not sure about what is 'item' here and how it works? Thank you.

Comment: I guessed on that bit really because it's not in your code... but you mentioned that you would like to "add another item with percentage value", so I'm saying that the percentage value is what you would pass to `publishProgress`.